# How can I update a group of accounts where unique identifier is not an Int (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Below is my table and the column I'm trying to update is the planID

```
AccountUsageID      AccountID      PLanID
38dkaie            1234            1
38d246e            1234            1
38dka41            1234            1
38dA38e            1234            1
3AKkaie            1234            1
3854E6e            1234            1
AEdka41            1234            1
IRKMdAe            1234            1
```

There are 8 accounts total and I want to update the planID to 1,2,3, in group of 2 account usuage per plan.

The final result should look like:

```
AccountUsageID      AccountID      PLanID
38dkaie            1234            1
38d246e            1234            1
38dka41            1234            2
38dA38e            1234            2
3AKkaie            1234            3
3854E6e            1234            3
AEdka41            1234            4
IRKMdAe            1234            4
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Do you want to update the `PlanId` column in the table or just produce a query with the `PlanId`?  What database are you using?

Comment: I want to update the values in the table. I'm using SQL 2012

Comment: Which Account Usage values end up in which PlanID is arbitrary?

Comment: I mistyped, it should be AccoutUsageID which is the UniqueID for this table, it has no correlation with the planID

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the `ROW_NUMBER()` function and some modulus division:

```
;with cte AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AccountID ORDER BY [Account Usage]) RN
              FROM TAble1
              )
UPDATE cte
SET PlanID = (RN-(RN-1)%2)/2+1
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9bf36/7/0)

This will ensure no more than 2 records per combination of `PLANID` and `ACCOUNTID`.  You can remove the `PARTITION BY AccountID` if you don't want `PLANID` to repeat for different `ACCOUNTID` values, likewise you can alter the `ORDER BY [Account Usage]` to suit your preferences.

The `ROW_NUMBER()` function assigns a number to each row. `PARTITION BY` is optional, but used to start the numbering over for each value in that group,  ie: if you `PARTITION BY Some_Date`  then for each unique date value the numbering would start over at 1.  `ORDER BY` of course is used to define how the counting should go, and is required in the `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

**Update:** You can adjust the number of items per set by simply changing the integer used in the modulus and division step, and you can test the results before performing the update by selecting it first:

```
;with cte AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AccountID ORDER BY [Account Usage]) RN
              FROM TAble1
              )
SELECT [Account Usage],AccountID, PlanID = (RN-(RN-1)%30)/30+1
FROM cte
```

Comment: Thanks so much Goat Co! If I have 120 accounts and I want to divide it into 4 plans (30 accounts = planID 6, 30 account = planID 10...ect), can you help?

Comment: You can remove the `PARTITION BY AccountID` portion if you don't want that to be factored into which `PlanID` the records end up in, and you can simply update the number used in the update query to select how many accounts per planID, ie 30 = `(RN-(RN-1)%30)/30+1`.

Comment: Why are you using that expression instead of `1 + ((RN - 1) / 30)`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff That is indeed cleaner, I can't recall the scenario for which I used my version, I know I was dealing with a running sum but perhaps it was never necessary.